# How to load .xib UIviews on ViewController in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

Hi i am very new for ios and in my app i am loading UIView using .xib files

when i click first buttons i want to load FirstView and remove otherviews
when i click second button i want to load SecondView and remove otherviews
when i click third button i want to load ThirdView and remove otherviews

### mycode:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize leftView,rightView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)FirstAction:(id)sender {

    FirstView * test1 = [[FirstView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rightView.frame.size.width, rightView.frame.size.height)];
    test1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [rightView addSubview:test1];
}

- (IBAction)SecondAction:(id)sender {

    SecondView * test2 = [[SecondView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rightView.frame.size.width, rightView.frame.size.height)];
    test2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [rightView addSubview:test2];
}

- (IBAction)ThirdAction:(id)sender {

    ThirdView * test3 = [[ThirdView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rightView.frame.size.width, rightView.frame.size.height)];
    test3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [rightView addSubview:test3];
}

@end
```

Comment: Try the solution provided by me

Comment: You said you are loading views using xib files. But you are creating them programmatically in your action methods. Do you have the xib files in your project?

Comment: yes i am having xib files in my project this is my sample app

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B05NQoG9RAmwd2NnU3AzVlRzdjg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this piece of code: I have written code for view which will remove previous view before adding the new one.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    FirstView * test1;
    SecondView * test2;
    ThirdView * test3;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize leftView,rightView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    test1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    test2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SecondView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    test3 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ThirdView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

}

- (IBAction)FirstAction:(id)sender {

   test1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rightView.frame.size.width, rightView.frame.size.height);
    test1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self removePreviousView:test1 FromSuperView:rightView];
    [rightView addSubview:test1];
}

- (IBAction)SecondAction:(id)sender {

    test2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rightView.frame.size.width, rightView.frame.size.height);
    test2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self removePreviousView:test2 FromSuperView:rightView];
    [rightView addSubview:test2];
}

- (IBAction)ThirdAction:(id)sender {

    test3.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rightView.frame.size.width, rightView.frame.size.height);
    test3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self removePreviousView:test3 FromSuperView:rightView];
    [rightView addSubview:test3];
}


- (void)removePreviousView:(UIView*)previousView FromSuperView:(UIView*)view{
    for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
        if (![subView isKindOfClass:[previousView class]]) {
            [subView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: please modified if there any mistacks ok brother?

Comment: did u check? brother

Comment: yeah I have checked you are doing several things in wrong way. Like you have set classes of the views in nib but you are not loading your view from nib.

Comment: can u send me that sample project if u modified please?

Comment: I have updated the code. Replace it with the code in your UIViewController and check out the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103466/discussion-between-abhiram-and-shehzad-ali).

Answer (score 1):

**1)**
Make view global

```
FirstView * test1;
SecondView * test2;
ThirdView * test3;
```

Remove from superview whenever you want:

```
[test1 removeFromSuperView];
```

**2)** Add tag to view

```
test1.tag = 10;
```

Remove view using tag value:

```
[(UIView*)[rightView  viewWithTag:10] removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: sorry for any type in snippet.

Comment: Hi @KDeogharkar  not adding xib UIview

Comment: so you are saying that view is not displaying?

Comment: first,second,third view is having xib?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103462/discussion-between-abhiram-and-kdeogharkar).

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. It contains a `loadXib:` call that loads the view from the nib with the given name and returns it.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    FirstView * test1;
    SecondView * test2;
    ThirdView * test3;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize leftView,rightView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(UIView*)loadXib:(NSString *)name
{
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:name bundle:nil];
    if (nib != nil)
    {
        NSArray *items = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        if (items != nil && items.count == 1)
        {
            return (UIView*)items[0];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (IBAction)FirstAction:(id)sender {

//   test1 = [[FirstView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rightView.frame.size.width, rightView.frame.size.height)];
    test1 = (FirstView*)[self loadXib:@"FirstView"];
    if (test1 != nil) {
        test1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        [rightView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        [rightView addSubview:test1];
    }
}

- (IBAction)SecondAction:(id)sender {

//    test2 = [[SecondView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rightView.frame.size.width, rightView.frame.size.height)];
    test2 = (SecondView*)[self loadXib:@"SecondView"];
    if (test2 != nil) {
        test2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[rightView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
            [rightView addSubview:test2];
        }
    }

- (IBAction)ThirdAction:(id)sender {

//    test3 = [[ThirdView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, rightView.frame.size.width, rightView.frame.size.height)];
    test3 = (ThirdView*)[self loadXib:@"ThirdView"];
    if (test3 != nil ) {
        test3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[rightView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
            [rightView addSubview:test3];
        }
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is method for your need.

/* Without tag */

```
- (void)removeSubviewsExpectView:(id)viewClass {

    for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {

         if (![subView isKindOfClass:[viewClass class]]) {

                [subView removeFromSuperview];

        }
    }

}
```

/* With tag */

```
- (void)removeSubviewsExpectView:(int)viewTag {

    for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {

        if (subView.tag != viewTag) {

            [subView removeFromSuperview];

        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly  you create `UiView` ***IBOutlets*** in the  ***NSBundle*** then you choose this method

```
- (IBAction)FirstAction:(id)sender {
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [rightView subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
     [v removeFromSuperview];
     }
  UIView *firstViewUIView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]   loadNibNamed:@"Test1" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
   [rightView containerView addSubview:firstViewUIView];
}

- (IBAction)SecondAction:(id)sender {

       NSArray *viewsToRemove = [rightView subviews];
       for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
         [v removeFromSuperview];
      }
       UIView *secondView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]   loadNibNamed:@"Test2" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
      [rightView containerView addSubview:seconView];  
}

- (IBAction)ThirdAction:(id)sender {

         NSArray *viewsToRemove = [rightView subviews];
         for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
          [v removeFromSuperview];
                   }
            UIView *thirdView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]   loadNibNamed:@"Test3" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
           [rightView containerView addSubview:thirdView];

}
```